# Script to backup and restore an Informix database

Tags: informix

I made this script to backup and restore an Informix database.  It's a menu with two functions that will give you two choices: to backup or restore a database.

The script will use dbexport then archive the backup to a directory.

To restore the database, I used dbimport.

```
#!/bin/sh
###################################################################################
#Usage  ./impexp.sh BASE USER ARCHIVE
###################################################################################
LOGO="DB IMPEXP"

#------------------------------------------------------
# Definition des variables
#------------------------------------------------------

BASE=$1
USER=$2
ARCHIVE=$3
export DBSTOR=/stored/bdd
export TEMPOF=/stored/tmp
ADATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
size_dbs=$(du "$BASE".exp |  sed -e 's/\t.*$//')
size_dbs2=$((size_dbs*4))


#------------------------------------------------------
# MENU PROMPTS
#------------------------------------------------------

ymenu="y.  backup BDD"              ;
zmenu="z.  restore archive "         ; 


#------------------------------------------------------
# MENU FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
#------------------------------------------------------
 
badchoice () { MSG="Invalid Selection ... Please Try Again" ; } 
 

ypick () {     echo "Backup BDD"
    #------------------------------------------------

    dbexport $BASE
    
    mkdir -m 0777 -p "$DBSTOR"
    
    tar -czvf $DBSTOR/$BASE.exp.$ADATE.tgz ./$BASE.exp && chmod 777 $DBSTOR/*

    rm -rf ./$BASE.exp
    rm -f  ./dbexport.out
 }
zpick () {     echo "Restoring archive"
    #---------------------------------------
    cd $DBPATH

    tar -xzvf $ARCHIVE
    
    onspaces -a dbs_"$BASE"_01 -p /bases_data/data_"$BASE"_01.dbs -o 0 -s ${size_dbs2}
    dbimport -q "$BASE" -d dbs_"$BASE"_01 
    echo "Import done"
  }

#------------------------------------------------------
# DISPLAY FUNCTION DEFINITION
#------------------------------------------------------

themenu () {
# clear the screen
clear
echo `date`
echo
echo "  " $LOGO
echo
echo " Please Select:"
echo
echo "   " $ymenu
echo "   " $zmenu
echo "   "
echo "   "
echo "     x. Exit"
echo
echo $MSG
echo
echo Select by pressing the letter and then ENTER ;
}
 
MSG=

while  true
do
  themenu

  read answer

  MSG=


  case $answer in
      y|Y) ypick;;
      z|Z) zpick;;


      x|X) break;;
 
        *) badchoice;;
 
  esac

  echo ""      
  echo "Press <ENTER> to return to the menu..."
  read junk
  clear
done
```

Sadly it doesn't work properly, especially the backup part where i have these error messages :

```
   create database
   225 - Cannot create file for system catalog (systables).
   131 - ISAM error: no free disk space
   ./impexp.sh: line 61: import_erreur: command not found
```

Thank you.

Comment: In what ways doesn't it work properly?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler To be honest i tried to use onbar as you've recommended before and i failed miserably, i couldn't understand how to use it on an interactive shell and store backup files, i used dbimport cause it was easier for me to understand but it was a huge mistake it takes too much time and it didn't work in some machines i have folders rights issues in others it's DB users privileges.

Comment: In the function `ypick`, there is an `else` and a `fi` with no starting `if`.  You should probably just use `mkdir -p "$DBPATH"` to create the directory.  You should not set the directory permissions to `777` IMO; that is a major security risk.  Use 775 or 755 instead.  On modern POSIX systems (Linux, etc), you should be able to specify `mkdir -m 0755 -p "$DBPATH"`.  Also note that the `DBPATH` environment variable has a specific meaning to Informix servers, though it is seldom used.  Apart from the broken shell syntax, what other problems are there in the backup option?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i edited the script i have a problem with the zpick function now shows error 225 and 131

Comment: The message about `import_erreur not found` is because `dbimport` reports failure with a non-zero exit status and your script then tries to invoke `import_erreur` but it isn't a function within the script and also isn't a program (script?) outside this one.  The lack of space error means your Informix server needs more disk space (add chunks to the relevant dbspaces), or you need to remove databases that are no longer needed.

Comment: Your question says "especially the backup part", and then refers to error messages about creating the database.  Should that 'backup' be 'restore'?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes the y pick function creates an export and the zpick will use that file to restore the database i think i have a problem with the creation of the 'dbs' file on the 'onspaces' command  i still have a large disk space so i taught it's caused by the size defined on the 'onspaces' command edited the script again now i have theses errors 'Space does not exist.' '*** create database'  '225'  '130'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion in comments and amendments to the question, the problem appears to be primarily in the 'recover' stage, and it may be that the trouble is with creating enough space in the dbspace.

I'm going to mention here that I find DB-Access distressing to use.  So distressing that I wrote a program now called `sqlcmd` to work the way I wish DB-Access did.  Consider using SQLCMD (available from the [IIUG Software
Archive](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL)), which
I wrote to behave consistently in shell scripting contexts whereas
DB-Access doesn't.
It dates back to 1986 (before there was `dbaccess`; in those days, you
used `isql` instead — DB-Access was carved out of `isql` in an
evening) and was originally called `rdsql`.
It bears no relation to Microsoft's johnny-come-lately program of the
same name — except for the name and having the same general purpose
(manipulate SQL databases).

I mention it because scripting for "is there already a dbspace called 'xyz'?"  becomes trivial:

```
dbspace="xyz"
if [ -n "$(sqlcmd -d sysmaster "select name from sysdbspaces where name = '$dbspace'") ]
then : dbspace exists - add space to it
else : dbspace does not exist - create it
fi
```

With DB-Access, this is harder.  What should work is something along the lines of:

```
dbspace="xyz"
result=$(dbaccess sysmaster - 2>/dev/null <<EOF
select name from sysdbspaces where name = '$dbspace';
EOF
)
if [ -n "$result" ]
then : dbspace exists - add space to it
else : dbspace does not exist - create it
fi
```

This code should be encapsulated into a shell function or a shell script called `dbspace_exists` that can be used by scripts.  It should return 0 or exit with status 0 if the dbspace exists; it should return a non-zero value or exit with a non-zero status if the dbspace does not exist.  (And it shouldn't generate any output by default!)  I'd use a script because the performance impact is negligible and the clarity and reusability is much simpler.  YMMV!

Chunk files must exist and have appropriate permissions before running `onspaces`.  The following works if the user running the script is `root` or has system administrator privileges.  Drop the
`chown` line if necessary, but note that if the owner is not user informix, group informix, the new chunk path may not work at all.

```
cp /dev/null "$chunkpath"
chown informix:informix "$chunkpath"
chmod 660 "$chunkpath"
```

Your code keeps repeating some constructs — use variables so you stay DRY ("Don't Repeat Yourself").

You have something along the lines of:

```
cd $DBSTOR          # Changed from DBPATH

tar -xzvf $ARCHIVE

onspaces -c -d dbs_"$BASE"_01 -p /bases_data/data_"$BASE"_01.dbs -o 0 -s ${size_dbs2}
dbimport -q "$BASE" -d dbs_"$BASE"_01 
echo "Import done"
```

I think you need something more like:

```
cd "${DBSTOR}" || exit 1

tar -xzvf "${ARCHIVE}"

dbspace_name="dbs_${BASE}_01"
dbspace_path="/bases_data/${dbspace_name}.dbs"
if [ -f "$dbspace_path" ]
then
    echo "$0: dbspace chunk file $dbspace_path already exists" >&2
    exit 1
fi
cp /dev/null "$dbspace_path"
chown informix:informix "$dbspace_path"
chmod 660 "$dbspace_path"

if dbspace_exists "$dbspace_name"
then onspaces -a    "$dbspace_name" -p "$dbspace_path" -o 0 -s "${size_dbs2}"
else onspaces -c -d "$dbspace_name" -p "$dbspace_path" -o 0 -s "${size_dbs2}"
fi
if [ "$?" != 0 ]
then
    echo "$0: failed to create/expand dbspace $dbspace_name" >&2
    exit 1
fi
if dbimport -q "$BASE" -d "$dbspace_name"
then echo "Import of $BASE done"
else
    echo "Import of $BASE failed" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Remove the files extracted from the tar file
rm -fr …

exit 0
```

You should do an archive before trying to use the new dbspace — I've not integrated that into the script.  Without the archive, the extra chunk may not be available.

There is still a lot of polishing to do.

Note the use of the braces in `dbspace_name="dbs_${BASE}_01"`.  This ensures that the variable name is `${BASE}` and not `$BASE_01`.  Your circumvention is effective but clumsy and not idiomatic shell.  I usually quote variables, and often embed the variable names in braces `"${dbspace_name}".  If you don't have spaces or strings touching the variable name, you can do without the extra punctuation, but it helps in the long run.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan as always your answers explain and teach at the same time thank you again