# Using Informix's onpladm command to backup and restore

Tags: informix

I have created a script, with your help to backup and restore an Informix database [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70020341/script-to-backup-and-restore-an-informix-database). As I'm new to Informix, I used `dbimport` and `dbexport`.

Now I found out about the `onpladm` command and I found that it can be used to create, load, or unload all tables in a database.

Can anyone explain how it works and what are the benefits of using it instead of `dbimport`/`dbexport`?